# Special relativity - what's the difference between the two problems?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

> Exercise 1:
> In frame $S$, event $B$ occurs $2 \cdot 10^{-6} \mathrm{ s}$  after event $A$ and at $\Delta x = 1.5 \mathrm{ km}$ from event $A$.
> (a) How fast must an observer be moving along the $+x$ axis so that events $A$ and $B$ occur simultaneously?

Then I encountered another exercise.

> Exercise 2: Observers in reference frame $S$ see an explosion located at $x_1 = 480 \mathrm{ m}$. A second explosion occurs $5 \cdot 10^{-6} \mathrm{ s}$ later at $x_2 = 1200 \mathrm{ m}$. In reference frame $S'$, which is moving along the $+x$ axis at speed $v$, the explosions occur at the same point in space. Determine $v$.

I believe them to be the same exercise, but they are in fact different. Would appreciate someone pointing out exactly why they ae different and what i misunderstood!

Comment: The fact that the two events are not simultaneous is clearly important and not taken into account in your second answer (without this fact, the events would be spacelike separated but you are asked to find a frame where there separation is clearly timelike, as they are at the same point in space).

Comment: I should mention that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation. However, since your question seemed quite close to "Why are these exercises actually different?", I chose to answer it. It would be nice to rephrase it, though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exercises are actually way different. Notice that in the first one, there is a frame of reference in which both events happen at the same *time*. Hence, they are spacelike related. In the second exercise, you are told there is a frame of reference in which both events happen at the same *location*, and hence they are timelike related. If two events are timelike related, there is no frame of reference in which both of them occur at the same time, and hence it makes sense that your calculation gave a value above the speed of light (you tried to find an impossible frame and got an impossible answer).

Another way of noticing this difference would be to compute the invariant interval between the events in both exercises. You will notice they have different signs, which is a great difference.

Comment: So in this case $\Delta x $ would be $0$? But how about the time component? Should i still use $t=5*10^{-6}s$? Ah i didnt know i can still ask questions when the post is closed...

Comment: ah 5 seconds after posted that i got it...ty

Answer (score 3):

Remember that you can use also another Lorentz equation. In this case, we are looking at a frame in which two events happen at the same point, not at the same time. Therefore, we must have $\Delta x'=0$ and thus $v=\Delta x/\Delta t$.